# 24 Electrical outlets replaced, only 12 work

Tags: electrical

My husband updated 20yr old outlets in our grandma's house. After replacing roughly 24 outlets only half of them (12) worked when we turn the power back on -- He went back and rechecked for loose wiring and all were connected. We also checked,double checked and triple checked the with the breaker box.

Comment: Most likely one or more outlets in the middle of a run are not feeding through to the rest. Open each outlet back up and check to ensure all hot and neutral wires are in fact connected.

Comment: Is there a pattern to which ones are working and which not? For example is downstairs OK but upstairs not? A photo of the open breaker box might help.

Comment: Did he use the bonds on the sides of the receptacles to feed power on? If so, are they all intact? You can see the bonds without pulling out the receptacles.

Comment: Your husband doesn't know what he's doing.  For that matter, did you verify the old outlets were live before removing them?

Comment: I find it hard to believe all 24 are on one circuit so unless you have a failed breaker in the panel feeding 12 outlets (still a bit to many on one breaker) either a multiple set of failures occurred or only leg in the panel is still is hot.  No matter what a voltage tester is needed to flow the flow.    I have seen and heard of the possibility of low budget outlets being bad in groups.

Comment: If they are daisy chained it should be a failry simple matter of finding the last one on the chain that is working. That is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like either there's something seriously wrong with a) the products he is using; or b) his methods in doing the work.

"Back stab" connections are a common source of problems.  These are a little hole you jab the wire into, on cheap outlets. It's easy to mess up and hard to realize it.  Electricians use them because they are cheap and they can work fast and make more money.  The quality is terrible and they tend to fail (which may relate to the question of why the old outlets need replacing).  I never use them.  I buy better outlets, such as the $3-4 ones, and use screw terminals or the "clamp-and-screw" method the better outlets allow. Here's a page comparing "cheap" and "better".
 https://www.handymanhowto.com/electrical-outlets-side-wire-versus-back-wire/

Another mistake is blindly replacing a bunch of outlets without testing each step of the way.  Power comes in from the panel and goes to the first receptacle in the chain, then from there to later outlets, typically by "passing through" the outlet. Understand the layout of the wiring, and work one outlet at a time.

There's also the mistake of breaking off the "tab" between the outlet screws, or using *used* outlets where you do not realize the tab is broken off. These separate the two outlets into separate circuits, so for instance one outlet can be always-on and the other can be switched with a light switch.  If you're trying to use both terminals or backstabs to pass-through an outlet with broken tabs, the pass-through won't work and that will kill downstream outlets.

Comment: grammar pedant objects to misuse of "begs the question."